# multiple regression in stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot the fitted values of a regression with multiple regressors using `stat_smooth()`. Looks like `stat_smooth()` only allows for a regression that uses the (x,y) data specified in the `aes` section of `ggplot`.

Here is a typical plot of the fit of the simple regression with `x=hp` and `y=mpg`

```
head(mtcars)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes=(x=hp, y=mpg))+geom_point()+
stat_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~x)
```

However, I would like to plot the same as above, but the fitted value should come from a regression with two regressors `x1=hp` and `x2=wt` for example.

The idea is, after controlling for `wt`, what is the relationship between `mpg` and `hp`.

Is this possible?

Comment: What should the plot look like? You certainly can't do this with stat_smooth. May plot multiple lines?

Comment: I would check out the ``margins`` package to do this. stat_smooth doesn't allow for multiple regressions, but with margins you can plot the marginal effects (eg Y ~ X + Z + X:Z)

Comment: Calculate the fits directly, and use `geom_ribbon`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no stats expert but I thought that multiple linear regression is no longer 2D once you add on extra dependent variables. See if this article takes you in the right direction:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73320/how-to-visualize-a-fitted-multiple-regression-model

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. I found it here, by [@aosmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2461552/aosmith):

https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/11/16/plot-fitted-lines/#plotting-predicted-values-with-geom_line

The short story is you separately fit your multiple regression model, add the fitted values to the original dataset, and then overwrite geom_line()'s aes with the fitted values.

This example will plot both the univariate regression line and the multivariate fitted line:

```
fitlm = lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = dat)
dat$fitted = predict(fitlm)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x1, y = y) ) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, color="blue", se=FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, aes(y = fitted), color="red", se=FALSE)
```